# JSON Error: Unterminated object on valid json text

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm having a problem with JSON. On my webspace I'm hosting a php file which converts a mysql request into JSON Format. Then a android device reads that JSON File and processes the data (temperature and humidity) in a graph.

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

// SQL Query abschicken
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classpidb ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1000");
    //Schleife bis alle Eintragungen in Array gespeichert
    $listenArray["Liste"] = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $listeneintrag = array();
        $listeneintrag["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $listeneintrag["Time"] = $row["Time"];
        $listeneintrag["Temp"] = $row["Temp"];
        $listeneintrag["Humi"] = $row["Humi"];
        array_push($listenArray["Liste"], $listeneintrag);
    }
    //Ausgabe im JSON Format
    $listenArray["Status"] = ["0","Select erfolgreich"];
    echo json_encode($listenArray);


//Verbindung trennen.
mysql_close($verbindung);

?>
```

JSON-Parsing in Android (result is the JSON-File read as string):

```
JSONObject jsonErgebnis = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray statusArray = jsonErgebnis.getJSONArray("Status");
            int status = statusArray.getInt(0);
            if(status == 0)
            {
                JSONArray datenArray = jsonErgebnis.getJSONArray("Liste");
                //for (int i = 0; i < datenArray.length(); i++) {
                for (int i = datenArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    JSONObject einzelsatz = datenArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ...

                firstdatatemp.addXValue(einzelsatz.getString("Time"));
                        firstdatatemp.addEntry(new Entry((float) einzelsatz.getDouble("Temp"), set.getEntryCount()), 0);

                        ...

                    // add a new x-value first
                    firstdatahumi.addXValue(einzelsatz.getString("Time"));
                    firstdatahumi.addEntry(new Entry((float) einzelsatz.getDouble("Humi"), set.getEntryCount()), 0);
                }
            }
```

If i use SELECT * FROM classpidb ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 100 it works fine. If i use 1000 instead of 100 I always get "Unterminated object at character ..." error. [CodeBeautifier](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) says my JSON text is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem:

Android didn't finish reading the full php response, so I replaced the buggy code for Reading the response with

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
}
```